# Using SELECT IN against 5 millions+ records

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of entries that is around 6 million in a text file. I have to check against table to return ALL rows are in text file. For that purpose I want to use `SEELCT IN`. I want to it is OK to convert all of them in a single query and run?

I am using MySQL.

Comment: Do you have write access on Database?

Comment: no. avoid using IN. better load that file is some temp table and apply join.

Comment: Your `IN` will basically end up in 6 millions `OR`, which will probably end up in that much of full table scans. Even if the query is accepted it will never complete before your server dies. A temp table and a JOIN on it is your best approach here.

Comment: What's SELECT IN? Why is it useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table or variable in Database insert the values into that table or variable and then you can perform IN operation like given below.

```
SELECT field
FROM table
WHERE value IN SELECT somevalue from sometable
```

Thanks